# Is there a way to resize a div based on an images size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently creating a custom media player for a customer with HTML and javascript. The customer only needs to add an empty element containing necessary data-attributes (such as preview-image, srcset, URL) to the site for the script to create a player unit.
The image and the media are siblings within the wrapping parent.
A click on the play button basically just hides the image and displays the media.

Player unit markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img class="preview-img" src="...">
<button class="play-button">Play</button>
<iframe class="embedded-media hidden">...</iframe>
</div>
```

The website owner now wants the size of the player to be dependent on the size of the preview image or srcset.
I tried to use the image as wrapper, but it's not a container element.
Is there any way to size the parent depending on the images size?

Comment: Did you try using JavaScript?

Comment: what do you suggest to use it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set any other element (except the image) inside the wrapper absolute and wrapper itself a inline-block, to allow automatic width. Then image makes wrapper to be the same ratio or size as itself.

When hiding the image after click, use relative positioning and z-index lower than the iframe (for example 10 in my example).

Set iframe size to 100%/100% to cover the same area as image and wrapper.

```html
<style>
<!--

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.play-button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 30;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: red;
}

.preview-img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
}

.embedded-media {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

-->
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
<img class="preview-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png">
<button class="play-button">Play</button>
<iframe class="embedded-media hidden">...</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I can handle the rest !